# Optimist Concurrency Check in node.js with mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, concurrency

I'm trying to implement some sort of [Optimist Concurrency Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) for a backend based on node & mongo.

Assuming the following:

User collection structured as such

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId, 
    "username" : String, 
    "password" : String, 
    "firstName" : String,
    "lastName" : String,
    "userData": {
       "comments": []
    },
    "__occ": Number
}
```

A Comment collection structured as such

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId,
    "text" : String
}
```

My backend defines a route to create new Comment and, once created, adds its ID to its creator's userData.comments array.

To test this route I created a small script which calls the route 10 times to create 10 Comments (using a for loop, nothing fancy)

I started to use mongoose but I had concurrency issues so I tried to use the native mongodb driver instead since I read that [Mongo operations on a single document are supposed to be atomic](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#does-mongodb-support-transactions)

To do so I used the `__occ` field to flag the status of a document and modified my update request to `(1) query on the _id plus __occ field ; (2) add a {$inc{ "__occ": 1}}` to increment the version number. If an update fails, I assume that I had a conflict, so I reload the object and try again. (see code below)

I basically can't get the thing to work, having various weirdness happening. Most of the time after a few successful iterations (1 or 2), a load (see console.log() with "BGCHECK #2.2" flag) returns an old (i.e. low __occ number) object yet the next update succeed and my comments array is messed up since all the changed made in the meantime are overwritten.

On the 10 new comments I was expecting, I have 4 or 5 once the loop completes (yet I have no exceptions whatsoever and never more than 10 top retries)

What am I doing wrong?

**Edited** sample "weirdness" when suddenly a find() returns an 'older' object. Message 'BGCHECK #2.2' is supposedly printed after I reload the object from the mongo DB to get the 'latest' values (first number is the timestamp of the console.log())
Last 4 lines are interesting: I had a 5 elements array which was returned twice already by the find() and then I somehow loose the last 2 entries
A similar situation also occurs once on line 16 when I loose one element ("575e500df16b51b3f64994c7")

```
    1465798669701 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994b9 to set => self.__occ = 0 => concurrency error => new object __occ=1 set = (#1 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8"])
    1465798669708 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994c7 to set => self.__occ = 0 => concurrency error => new object __occ=1 set = (#1 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8"])
    1465798669712 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994c6 to set => self.__occ = 0 => concurrency error => new object __occ=1 set = (#1 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8"])
    1465798669714 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994c8 to set => self.__occ = 0 => concurrency error => new object __occ=1 set = (#1 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8"])
    1465798669722 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994cb to set => self.__occ = 0 => concurrency error => new object __occ=1 set = (#1 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8"])
    1465798669725 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994cd to set => self.__occ = 0 => concurrency error => new object __occ=2 set = (#2 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9"])
    1465798669726 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994ca to set => self.__occ = 0 => concurrency error => new object __occ=2 set = (#2 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9"])
    1465798669728 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994c9 to set => self.__occ = 0 => concurrency error => new object __occ=2 set = (#2 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9"])
    1465798669732 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994cc to set => self.__occ = 0 => concurrency error => new object __occ=2 set = (#2 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9"])
    1465798669741 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994c7 to set => self.__occ = 1 => concurrency error => new object __occ=3 set = (#3 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd"])
    1465798669750 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994c6 to set => self.__occ = 1 => concurrency error => new object __occ=3 set = (#3 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd"])
    1465798669752 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994c8 to set => self.__occ = 1 => concurrency error => new object __occ=3 set = (#3 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd"])
    1465798669758 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994cb to set => self.__occ = 1 => concurrency error => new object __occ=3 set = (#3 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd"])
    1465798669764 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994ca to set => self.__occ = 2 => concurrency error => new object __occ=4 set = (#4 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd","575e500df16b51b3f64994c7"])
    1465798669772 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994c9 to set => self.__occ = 2 => concurrency error => new object __occ=4 set = (#4 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd","575e500df16b51b3f64994c7"])
    1465798669778 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994cc to set => self.__occ = 2 => concurrency error => new object __occ=3 set = (#3 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd"])
    1465798669792 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994c8 to set => self.__occ = 3 => concurrency error => new object __occ=4 set = (#4 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd","575e500df16b51b3f64994cc"])
    1465798669794 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994c6 to set => self.__occ = 3 => concurrency error => new object __occ=4 set = (#4 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd","575e500df16b51b3f64994cc"])
    1465798669798 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994cb to set => self.__occ = 3 => concurrency error => new object __occ=4 set = (#4 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd","575e500df16b51b3f64994cc"])
    1465798669815 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994ca to set => self.__occ = 4 => concurrency error => new object __occ=5 set = (#5 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd","575e500df16b51b3f64994cc","575e500df16b51b3f64994c6"])
    1465798669825 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994c9 to set => self.__occ = 4 => concurrency error => new object __occ=5 set = (#5 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd","575e500df16b51b3f64994cc","575e500df16b51b3f64994c6"])
    1465798669838 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994cb to set => self.__occ = 4 => concurrency error => new object __occ=3 set = (#3 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd"])
    1465798669864 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994ca to set => self.__occ = 5 => concurrency error => new object __occ=3 set = (#3 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd"])
    1465798669869 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994c9 to set => self.__occ = 5 => concurrency error => new object __occ=3 set = (#3 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd"])
    1465798669940 >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add 575e500df16b51b3f64994c9 to set => self.__occ = 3 => concurrency error => new object __occ=4 set = (#4 elts, ["575e500df16b51b3f64994b8","575e500df16b51b3f64994b9","575e500df16b51b3f64994cd","575e500df16b51b3f64994ca"])
```

PS: I can share more detailed logs or anything if useful

Code from the various pieces I mentioned

*Test script*

```
    const when = require('when');
    const request = require('request-promise');

    let promiseArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        promiseArray.push($createComment("Test comment #"+i));
    }

    return when.all(promiseArray).then(function(array) {
            // do something with array
    }

    function $createComment(text) {
            let options = {
                    method: "POST",
                    uri: "<uri>",
                    json: true
            };
            return request(optionsToMyRoute);
    }
```

*Backend code*

```
app.post("<uri>", function(req, res, next() {
    // do create Comment
    const commentId = // id of the comment I just created; no issue here so I'm skipping that code
    const creator = // User class that adds a few methods including addToSet & dbAddToSet (see below)

    creator.addToSet("userData.comments", commentId);
});
```

*User class*

```
// User objects have the same properties as the underlying's Collection (_id, __v, userData.comments, ...)

User.prototype.addToSet = function(property, value) {
    const self = this;

    function $addToSet(dbObj, retries) {
        if (retries === undefined) retries = 100;

        return dbObj.dbAddToSet(property, value, options).then(
            function(valuesAddedList) {
                return when.resolve(valuesAddedList);

            }, function(err) {
                if (err instanceof ConcurrencyDBError) { // Own Error class to identify & handle conflicts
                    let $refreshedObject = self._convert(err.object); // convert a JSON into a proper User object

                    const $dbObjProp = u.getProperty(dbObj, property);
                    const $refreshedObjProp = u.getProperty($refreshedObject, property);
                    debug("::ADDTOSET::$ADDTOSET::LOG Concurrency error trying to add %s to {__v: %d, set: #%s elts} => retrying with refreshed object {__v: %d, set: #%d elts} (retries=%d)", value, dbObj.__v, $dbObjProp ? $dbObjProp.length : "na", $refreshedObject.__v, $refreshedObjProp ? $refreshedObjProp.length : "na", retries);

                    if (retries > 0) {
                        return $addToSet($refreshedObject, retries-1);
                    } else {
                        err.message += " => max number of retries reached, failing";
                    } 
                }
                // else
                const message = err.message || "::ADDTOSET::$ADDTOSET::ERROR Unexpected error";
                return when.reject(GenericError.create(message, err)); // GenericError is a simple Error wrapper
            }
        );
    }

    return $addToSet(self);
}

User.prototype.dbAddToSet = function(property, value, options) {
    var self = this;

    // Use __occ to ensure we have the proper version of the object
    const $id = new ObjectID(self._id);
    const query = {
        '_id': $id,
        '__occ': self.__occ
    };
    const update = {
        '$addToSet': {},
        '$inc': {'__occ': 1}
    };

    let defer = when.defer();

    console.log("\t%s >>> BGCHECK #1 >>> Trying to add %s to set => self.__occ = %d, self.set = (#%s elts, %j) (query=%j, update=%j)", Date.now(), value, self.__occ, $property ? $property.length: "na", $property, query, update);

    self.$getMongoCollection().updateOne(query, update, { w: "majority", j: true }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) return defer.reject(err);

        const updateResult = result.result; // Expect a {ok, n, nModified}

        if ((updateResult.ok == 1) && (updateResult.n == 0)) {
            console.log("\t%s >>> BGCHECK #2.1 OCC >>> Trying to add %s to set => self.__occ = %d => concurrency error, loading new object", Date.now(), value, self.__occ);
            self.$getMongoCollection().find({_id: $id}).toArray(function(err, results) {
                if (err) return when.reject(err);

                const obj = results[0];

                // >>> debug
                let $objProp = u.getProperty(obj, property);
                console.log("\t%s >>> BGCHECK #2.2 OCC >>> Trying to add %s to set => self.__occ = %d => concurrency error => new object __occ=%d set = (#%s elts, %j)", Date.now(), value, self.__occ, obj.__occ, $objProp ? $objProp.length : "na", $objProp);
                // <<< debug

                return defer.reject(new ConcurrencyDBError(util.format("Concurrency error trying to update Object with __occ == %d", self.__occ), obj));
            });
        }  else {
            console.log("\t%s >>> BGCHECK #3 OK >>> Trying to add %s to set => self.__occ = %d => successfull, self.set = (#%s elts, %j) (updateResult=%j)", Date.now(), value, self.__occ, $property ? $property.length: "na", $property, updateResult);
            return defer.resolve(true);
        }
    });
    return defer.promise;
}

function $getMongoCollection() {
    // returns a properly initialized Mongo collection
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be much easier with [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate)?

Comment: Thanks for the hint @robertklep. findOneAndUpdate doesn't return the latest document since I have to query with {_id, __occ} to edge against potential conflicfts haven't I? But I figured it was worth a try since Mongo doc claims that it performs an atomic read & write operation. Unfortunately I have the same issue as the one I illustrated with the log extract above :( At some stage the (BGCHECK 2.2) find() returns an object which has fewer elements than in the queries before and it breaks the logic :(

Comment: `findOneAndUpdate` will return the latest document if you ask it to (`returnOriginal : false`). Also, you don't have to use `occ` in that case because it's an atomic operation: it will find _and_ update the document in one go, without the chance of another writer updating the same document.

Comment: Tried it without __occ but ran into the same issue which made me look into concurrency issues so I added back the __occ flag but it still didn't work :( (even if it would have, why wouldn't it work if I try to update 2 fields at the same time?) See my other question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803572/issue-with-single-document-concurrent-read-and-write-operations-in-mongodb-nod