# MongoDB Concurrent read/write on single document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, concurrentmodification

I'm having an issue with concurrent reads and writes on MongoDB, and was wondering if there was a simple solution embedded within the DB system.

I have an object that collects statistics for an app, and is represented on MongoDB as a single document in its own collection:

```
{
    "animals": {
        "cats": 0,
        "dogs": 0
}
```

The problem is that whenever a user adds a cat to their profile, i get the document, increase `cats` count and write the doc. However, if a user adds a `dog` just after the cat, the document read would be 0-0 and would write 0-1 instead of 1-1.

It's a typical concurrent read/write but I was wondering if there is a way to prevent this without adding my own locking system. Thanks!

Also: Cats and dogs is a simple example, I'm hosting a chat statistics db (messages sent, received, error...).

Not related: [Issue with single document concurrent read and write operations in mongodb / node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803572/issue-with-single-document-concurrent-read-and-write-operations-in-mongodb-nod)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, you could use the increment operator `$inc` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) instead of a read followed by a write.

`$inc` is an atomic operation, and hence should not case the issue you have with read, and then writing

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! I hope no more concurrent reads/answers happen ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think it is related to "watchify" it's a tool for concurrent read and write.

If you install it, it will be monitoring the changing and applying to the front-end.